# I want to save sort result from dropdown list wih paging in php &mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, sorting

Hello everyone: I have a problem on my site is working on them. I searched on  a solution for 5 days and  I can't find any result I needed it...

**in short :** I have list of car and I want to sort it by price descending and  ascending use dropdown list and I used paging to split the record to 5 item in one page ..

when I choose for example a descending from drop down list it's show the result successful but when i go to the next page in paging the sort it's lost..

I trying use SESSION but isn't worked yet and still when I press on next page keep the sorting lost

I do modify update on the code after first replay but problem still exist:(

this is my html code:

```
 <?php session_start();?>

   <select name="price"  id="price" class="css-dropdowns" tabindex="1" >
                                    <option value="0">Price Ascending</option>
                                    <option value="1">Ascending</option>
                                    <option value="2">Descending</option>
                                </select>
```

this my code to paging:

```
$select_demo="select c.car_id, car_name,price,model_year,drive_traine,mile_age,exterior_color,interior_color,mbg,stocke_num,vin_num,video_url,image,body_style,cylinders_num,displacement,gearbox_speed,gearbox_type,brand_name
from car as c join car_body as cb
on c.car_id=cb.car_id
join engine as e
on c.car_id=e.car_id
join brand as b 
on b.brand_id = c.brand_id
join transmission as t 
on c.car_id=t.car_id";


if(!$demo_result=$db->query($select_demo))
{
die ($db->error);   
}

$recored_count=$demo_result->num_rows;
$recored_limit=5;
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
$page=$_GET['page'];//+1
}
else
{
$page=1;

}
$offset=($page-1)*$recored_limit;
$total_page=ceil($recored_count / $recored_limit );

?>
```

this is query to show data and sort:

```
    $sql_paging="select c.car_id,car_name,price,model_year,drive_traine,mile_age,exterior_color,interior_color,mbg,stocke_num,vin_num,video_url,image,body_style,cylinders_num,displacement,gearbox_speed,gearbox_type,brand_name
    from car as c join car_body as cb
    on c.car_id = cb.car_id
    join  engine as e
    on c.car_id = e.car_id
    join brand as b 
    on b.brand_id = c.brand_id
    join transmission as t 
    on c.car_id = t.car_id"; 
    //to submit the dropdown list to get sort i want  
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    { 
   { 

    $_SESSION["price_filter"]=$_POST["price_filter"]; // call the ajax function to submit price drop down list
    if (isset($_SESSION["price_filter"]) && !empty ($_SESSION["price_filter"])) 
    {
         //query to show price 1 result
       if ($_SESSION["price_filter"] == 1)
          {
       $sql_paging.=" order by price asc";

          }
        else if($_SESSION["price_filter"] == 2)
         {
    $sql_paging.=" order by price desc";
          $_SESSION["price"]=($price ==2);
          } 
        } //end of if filter

    }//end of if request

    $sql_paging.=" LIMIT $offset,$recored_limit";

    if(!$paging_result=$db->query($sql_paging))
    {
    die ($db->error);   
    }

    while($row=$paging_result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
    ##I don't paste all of codes it's just part of them for example ##
    <code> echo "price".$row["price"]; }
```

this part of pagination with session to keep sort result when i go to next page

```
<!-- 1 st page-->  
<li class=""> <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?page="."1"."&f=".$_SESSION["price_filter"]?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>

<?php  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_page; $i++)

{?>

<li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?page=".$i."&f=".$_SESSION["price_filter"]?>"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>

<?php } // end of for  ?> 

<!-- last page-->                            
<li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?page=".$total_page ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
```

finally this is first question and first try to question on this site 
can anybody help me to fixed this code ..

and sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

You must define $offset, like:

```
$offset=$i*$recored_limit;
```

$recored_limit also need to be defined,try:

```
$recored_limit=5;
```

LIMIT return you $recored_limit record from $offset;
For saving filter asceding:

```
$_SESSION["price_filter"]=$_POST["price_filter"]
...
if ($_SESSION["price_filter"] == 1){
   $sql_paging.=" order by price asc";
}
elseif($_SESSION["price_filter"] == 2){
   $sql_paging.=" order by price desc";
}
```

Comment: I added apart of paging in main question I tried solved my code by your 


modified but the problem still exist 


`$_SESSION["price_filter"]=$_POST["price_filter"]; // call the ajax function to submit price drop down list if (isset($_SESSION["price_filter"]) && !empty ($_SESSION["price_filter"])) { //query to show price 1 result if ($_SESSION["price_filter"] == 1) { $sql_paging.=" order by price asc"; } else if($_SESSION["price_filter"] == 2) { $sql_paging.=" order by price desc"; $_SESSION["price"]=($price ==2); } } //end of filter`

Comment: 1) Does pageing work?

2) try to modify 
     $_SESSION["price_filter"]=$_POST["price_filter"];
to 
    if(isset($_POST["price_filter"])){
    $_SESSION["price_filter"]=$_POST["price_filter"];
    }

Comment: Do you start`s session? What does var_dump($_SESSION); output?

Comment: the paging work ..
i try this modified and problem still exist :/
i don't know how can i fix it ..!!

Comment: when I refresh the page without choosing any sort this value on screen string(1) "2"

Comment: Why you check if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') ? Try to remove this check.

Comment: I remove it but still problem exist .. I will by change method from post to get and check this solution